# Meaning of article 22 and 7 of the UN charter (about organs of the UN)

Tags: law, united-nations

In my opinion, article 22 and part of 7 of the UN charter seem a bit vague, and I can’t understand exactly what they means.
Article 22 is:

> The General Assembly may establish such subsidiary organs as it deems necessary for the performance of its functions.

Do these subsidiary organs last for one assembly, a specified duration of time, or forever?

Excerpt from article 7

> Such subsidiary organs as may be found necessary may be established in accordance with the present Charter.

Can somebody explain what these two articles mean? They seem a bit vague and weirdly worded to me, and I can’t understand them.

Comment: It seems pretty standard to me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do these subsidiary organs last for one assembly, a specified duration of time, or forever?

They last as long as their constituting document says they last.  For example, the Board of Auditors was established by the GA in 1946.  The [resolution](https://undocs.org/en/A/RES/74(I)) that did so provides for three members with staggered three-year terms, and that every year a new auditor is appointed for a three-year term.  I chose the example of the Board of Auditors from the GA's [page on the topic of subsidiary organs](https://www.un.org/en/ga/about/subsidiary/).

> Can somebody explain what these two articles mean? They seem a bit vague and weirdly worded to me, and I can’t understand them.

They just mean that the GA can establish groups for various purposes.  The articles are intentionally vague because their point is to give the GA fairly broad power to organize its business as it sees fit.